# Display servlet result in another iframe

Tags: java, servlets, iframe

I am studying servlets these days. I had no problems calling a servlet from a HTML page. There are two iframes on my index.html. The iframe on the left ist for the search bar and the navigation, and the iframe on the right is for the content.

As I said, I have no problem calling a servlet when it is for the iframe itself. The iframe reference is simply the servlet that will give me the navigation.

My question: I want to post search words in my search bar and get the result in the OTHER iframe (the content) How can I implement this? How can I 'send' the servlet from the left iframe to the right one?

Comment: Maybe not what you want to hear, but don't use iFrames. Use AJAX. This is 2015, frames should be confined to the annals of history by now.

Comment: Well, I heard that iframes are not that good.But this is a part of a big univeristy project and our professor wrote that we have to use iframes for whatever reason.

Comment: you can address one iframe from the other with `window.parent.<idOfOtherIframe>`

Comment: What if I implement a servlet that returns the HTML in another iFrame? Is this not possible?

Comment: @DennisvonEich you set some flag="right" in servlet while sending data to html. there call one javascript method on page load. check value of flag is right or left. if its right then show data in right iframe.